# speify in a list that states that each element is a string or an integer?

Tags: dart

How can I write a for loop in a list that states that each element is a string or an integer?

for example
var score=[gold, 3, bronze, silver, 4]

```
for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {     
if (score[i] == int) {
          print('int');
        }}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {

     if (score[i] == String) {
              print('String');
            }}
```

is it possible in dart.

Comment: Use the `is` operator like: `if (score[i] is String)`. For more information, read the following section in the Dart Language Tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

Comment: :) easy solution thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should first say that having lists containing multiple different types of data (where the common interface is `Object`) is not a sound design, in most cases, and does show a bad data model.

What you are looking for is the `is`-operator documented here in the Dart Language Tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

With this, you can write the following code. I have also replaced your normal for-loop with a for-each loop since that is better if you don't need to `i` variable and just want to iterate over the list.

```
void main() {
  var score=['gold', 3, 'bronze', 'silver', 4];

  for (final element in score) {
    if (element is String) {
      print('Scrore is the following String: $element');
    } else if (score is int) {
      print('Scrore is the following int: $element');
    } else {
      print('The score is not a String or int');
    }
  }
}
```